# Does "attacks" in effect text refer to attempted or only successful attacks?

Tags: dnd-4e

The cleric attack 'Halo of Consequence' hit text includes:

> ...and after the target attacks you or any ally, it is dazed until the end of its next turn.

Does this use of the word "attacks" mean that the target has to actually hit, or just attempt the attack?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Attempts.**

"Attack" and "hit" are game terms with specific meanings. If it was meant to only trigger on a successful attack, it would say hit.

Consider defenders' marks: they apply a penalty to the attack roll before it's known whether the attack will hit or miss, because they're triggered by an *attack* rather than a hit.